# trapped in bash traps (RETURN trap)

Tags: bash, trap

I am looking for an idiomatic pattern to use traps as a meaning "ensure" or "finally", so they should execute no matter how a bash function exits.

I've found the `RETURN` trap, but nesting that is not trivial. I guess the trap inside bar shadows the trap in foo. How can I set up traps for both `foo` and `bar`

So given the following code, I'd like to have cleanup when exiting `foo` and exiting `bar`.

My first attempt was to have a global string storing the cleanup tasks, but that one breaks whenever you have subshells. And it seems from the output of the following code, that RETURN signal is also "shell-global"

```bsh
fooclear() { echo fooclear; }
barclear() { echo barclear; }
bar() {
  echo bar
  trap barclear RETURN INT ERR TERM EXIT
  sleep 1
}

foo() {
  echo foo
  sleep 1
  trap fooclear RETURN INT ERR TERM EXIT
  bar
}

for i in 1 2 3; do
  foo &
done
wait
```

And a warning: to avoid duplicate handling, one must somehow administer that a clearing function has already completed.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but it seems like adding:

`trap - RETURN`

as the last command in the trap handler, causes the trap to revert to the previous one (`bash` is keeping a stack of `RETURN` handlers somewhere. The documentation says that in general `trap - {SIGSPEC}` causes the trap to revert to the default; I guess in this case, the default is the 'shadowed' trap command.

Comment: It's more complex than this. Calling `trap - [SIG_SPEC]` doesn't revert to previous trap, it reverts to ["the value it had upon entrance to the shell"](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). This could be blank, or inherited from the parent shell. It wil _not_ revert to one you previously set in the current shell. There is no trap stack other than that created each time you spawn a subshell. In other words if you set a trap for a given SIG_SPEC and then set it again the first one is [replaced by the second](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170415/12907).

Answer (score 1):

Correct, RETURN signal is shell-global, as are all of the signals. Trapping any signal [*replaces*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170415/12907) any trap already set on that signal which is probably what you mean by "shadows".

Traps afford some simple exception handling but for something more robust I'd check the answers to this stackoverflow question about [TRY/CATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22009364/78792)